# Literary quotations

Tags: formatting

I am writing a paper which I want to start with a literary quotation.  How do I do this?  It should probably appear above my name and the title.  It is not "To be or not to be" but for the purposes of my question it might as well be.

Comment: It may depend on the class and the general settings you are using (therfore, it's always good to include a minimal working example of your code). Anyway, have a look to `epigraph` package.

Answer (score 0):

I did this *without another package* using **white non-enumerated section headers** which are not listed in the Table of Contents, which is printed after this section.

```
\newpage
\section*{ \color{white} phantom}
   \vspace{.5\linewidth}
   \textit{To be or not to be}\\
   \vspace{.2cm}
   - Hamlet
   \newpage
\section*{ \color{white}  phantom}
\vspace{.5\linewidth}
```

Comment: I guess that such a result could be achieved even without the "phantom" sections, just using `\vspace*`s, or even better (if you want the citation to be right aliged) a `flushright` environment. White text (which does require `color` or `xcolor` package) has the important downside that if you copy and paste from pdf the text is there...

Comment: I will try it when I need it next, thanks

Comment: How to make your PDF even more confusing for visually-impaired readers? I assume screen-reading software won't care what colour the text is. You also shouldn't ever break a line with `\\ ` outside a `tabular` or similar. This method will also get strange results if you use `hyperref`.

Comment: Feel free to edit my post to make it clear on how it shall look like. All I know is - it worked for me and might help the person who asked for help in the first place.